# The "injectBabelPlugin" helper has been deprecated as of v2.0. You can use customize-cra plugins in replacement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to customize my imports using babel. I am following this link:

https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-tips-working-with-relative-path-using-create-react-app-fe55c5f97a21

This is my config-overrides.js

```
const { injectBabelPlugin } = require('react-app-rewired');

const rootImportConfig = [
    "root-import",
    {
        rootPathPrefix: "~",
        rootPathSuffix: "src"
    }
];

module.exports = config => injectBabelPlugin(rootImportConfig, config);
```

Package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
```

Currently, this gives me an error that:
The "injectBabelPlugin" helper has been deprecated as of v2.0. You can use customize-cra plugins in replacement

Hence, I installed

```
nom install customize-cra react-app-rewired --dev
```

and changed 'react-app-rewired' to 'customize-cra' in my js file as suggested here:
https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra#available-plugins

However, that still doesn't work since the `injectBabelPlugin` is also depreciated. What the function should I use here then? I tried the config files from here but it doesn't work from me either. It's src-functionality is also different.

https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/348

How can I fix my config file and imports? Instead of

```
import { ResultAlert } from '../../components/alerts/ResultAlert';
```

I want to do something like this:

```
import {ResultAlert} from '~/components';
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve what you want here without having to resort to hacking the `react-scripts`. Simply use a `baseUrl` configuration in your `jsconfig.js` or `tsconfig.ts` file. More details in this blog post: https://dev.to/mr_frontend/absolute-imports-in-create-react-app-3ge8

But essentially:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Then you can do things like `import Home from "components/Home"` and it'll just work.